# DHIS2-live is not working properly in windows

Tags: dhis-2

I am new to use DHIS for giving a try to see what I can do with DHIS and its applications. I have installed PostgreSQL and DHIS2-Live and updated its configuration. When it starts after taking sometimes, it displays on the browser:

HTTP ERROR 503
Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
Service Unavailable
```

If anyone can help with on how to install and use DHIS 2 or DHIS2-Live on windows 7?

Comment: Have you tried searching for error logs?

Comment: In the root log directory of DHIS2-Live is nothing. Could you point where I can find the logs? I am not much familiar with Java Environment and Jetty and that is why I have selected the live ready made version.

Answer (score 0):

dhis2 live is not very stable , infact , doesnt work in all environments.
instead its better to go for manual installation , which is explained in dhis2 official site